# Find exact value or approximation for double sum function

Tags: summation, factorial

I have a double sum function as
\begin{align*}
F = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{(i \times j)\lambda^{i+j}}{(i+j)!}
\end{align*}

I tried to transform it to the form of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=2}f(n)\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}$ to apply the Power Series Expansion for Exponential Function, but could not find the pattern for $f(n)$.

Could you give me some hints about how to conduct the transform? Or the approximation for the function $F$? I'm very appreciated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate this explicitly collecting equal powers of $\lambda$.

We have

$$\sum_{i+j=n;i,j\geq 1}ij = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i(n-i)=n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2$$

$$= n\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}$$
$$= \frac{n^3-n}{6}$$

Hence,
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \sum^{\infty}_{j=1} \frac{(i \times j)\lambda^{i+j}}{(i+j)!} = \frac 16\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(n^3-n)\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really appreciated your answer.

Comment: @M.bara : Again you are welcome :-).